# How to hide and expand a footer on hover?

Tags: html, css

First how do I hide part of the footer and only show the full footer when the mouse hover on ? is this possible with only HTML5 and CSS ?

```
<div class="footer"> Copyright 
    <div id="hidden"> 
        <p> content </p> 
        <p> content </p> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hidden {display:none}
```

No idea how to make it slide up when the mouse in on the footer bar and how do I make it transition of slide up ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using CSS transitions. What is your code so far?

Comment: <div class="footer">
Copyright
<div id="hidden">
<p> content </p>
<p> content </p>
</div>
</div>

css-
#hidden
{display:none}

no idea how to make it slide up when the mouse in on the footer bar....and how do i make it transition of slide up ?
TQ

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to a similar problem:

```
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    transition-duration: 0.300s;
}

#footer:hover {
    height: 100px;
}
```

You can probably also do something like `div.footer:hover #hidden {height: 100px}` which changes one element—`#hidden`—when another element—`div.footer`—is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the user mousing over? The footer? If so, yes, it's very possible with the :hover pseudo.

```
#footer {height:100px;overflow:hidden;}
#footer:hover {height:auto;}
```

Comment: <div class="footer">
Copyright
<div id="hidden">
<p> content </p>
<p> content </p>
</div>
</div>

css-
#hidden
{display:none}

no idea how to make it slide up when the mouse in on the footer bar....and how do i make it transition of slide up ?
TQ

Comment: @user2982110, My solution will only make an instantaneous popup. To slide, you'll either need to use JS, or transitions as somebody mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Well, with your code, make it #footer:hover #hidden {display:block}

Answer (score 0):

You should make the hidden part of the footer the child of the entire footer and then you  can simply add something like the following to your CSS:

```
#hidden-footer {
    display: none;
}
#footer-wrapper:hover #hidden-footer {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: <div class="footer">
Copyright
<div id="hidden">
<p> content </p>
<p> content </p>
</div>
</div>

css-
#hidden
{display:none}

no idea how to make it slide up when the mouse in on the footer bar....and how do i make it transition of slide up ?
TQ